# How to break FOR loop in simulink

Tags: for-loop, simulink, break

In Simulink, I have a signal that is a 1-D array.
I want to get the index of the first value other than 0, but the result received is the index of the last non-zero value
[image]
I am new to Simulink, is there any way to break FOR loop?
Or what should I do in this case
Any hint will be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a for loop iterator subsystem, use the [while iterator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/whileiterator.html) subsystem.

From the properties you can enable the "Show iteration number port" option to give you the index to increment over the items in the array.
The while iterator also has a "cond" or condition input which you can set to exit the while loop when you get to a non-zero value.

Alternatively, use the for loop but work from the end of the array towards the front and output the last non-zero value which will be the first non-zero value if you worked in a forwards direction.
Use the length minus the index value to access the array to work backwards.